# Really confused for these snippets based on Time Complexity

Tags: java, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Hi guys i had a confusion for a long time on time complexity for two code snippets

For instance lets take a list , that list has n items but in the next line I initialize it to a new instance of ArrayList.

```
   List<Integer> temp = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
   temp = new ArrayList<>(); // I believe the time complexity is O(1)
```

So guys in the above snippet is it really O(1) coz it creates a new instance object and points to it or am i wrong here?

The other snippet is

```
   int counter = any value;
   for(int i = 0;i<n;i*=counter)// I guess its O(n)
```

In the above snippet i guess its O(n) coz counter is variable and can have any random value which is not fixed or is it log(n) ?

Please do throw some light on this guys, Thanks.

Comment: "I believe the time complexity is O(1)" are you asking about the time complexity of both lines together, or just the reassignment?

Comment: "I guess its O(n)" this executes infinitely, unless `n < 0`. If you mean to initialize `i = 1`, then it's logarithmic.

Comment: Reassignment alone , now my confusion is cleared thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. So guys in the above snippet is it really O(1) coz it creates a new instance object and points to it or am i wrong here?

Line 1 `List<Integer> temp = List.of(1,2,3,4,5)` is **O(n)**. Under the hood, Java actually iterates through the elements to do null checks before setting them into the underlying array held by the List.

Line 2 `temp = new ArrayList<>()` is **O(1)**. The amount of time it takes to initialize the new list is constant; there is no variable here.

When you consider the entire snippet as a whole (Lines 1 + 2 together), it is **O(n)**, because we always take the highest complexity in the algorithm.

---

> 2. In the above snippet i guess its O(n) coz counter is variable and can have any random value which is not fixed or is it log(n) ?

Given that you initialized the loop as `i = 1` instead, and that both `n` and `counter` are variables and not constants, the time complexity would be **O(log <sub>counter</sub> n)**.

In the loop, the amount of iterations left is reduced(divided) by a factor of `counter` after each iteration. Hence the time complexity is logarithmic. You can think of "log <sub>c</sub> n" as saying "starting with `n`, the number of times you need to recursively divide by `c` in order to reach 1".

---

However, if you really meant to initialize the loop as `i = 0`, it would just execute infinitely.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation buddy , really appreciate it :-)

Comment: No problem, you're most welcome :)